# Export my Enterprise Wiki aspx pages to a PDF files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, development, javascript

Our client has asked if we can add a link to their current Wiki pages named "Export to PDF", so when the user click on the link the Wiki content will be exported inside a pdf file ?

i got confused if sharePoint 2013 support such a feature out of the box or not ? If not then can i write a web part or a javaScript code to implement this scenario ?

Thanks in advance for any help ..

Answer (score 3):

There is no such feature out of the box . You need to write your own code for achieving it. something like

```
protected void ExporttoPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExporttoPDF.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
}
```

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673592/export-to-pdf-in-sharepoint-custom-web-part)

Comment: thanks for the code, but how i should add this code to my SharePoint site, i mean should i add the code as a web part, or as a JavaScript ?

Comment: the code is C#, so you can add it as web part.

Comment: i am not sure how i will be converting to pdf ? will i gave to add a link to my wiki Pages which will call the Web Part ?